# How do I calculate for the following #Vus,AVG transaction time,iteration for multiple script in loadrunner?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, loadcontrol

You need to setup a scenario around the following parameters:

- List item
- You have a maximum of 1000 vus
- You have 10 scripts, each with an init, one action (with multiple steps) and an end. The minimum total transaction time (init+action+end) for each script is 1 minute (assume time spent in the init and end steps =0).
- All of the odd number scripts need to generate a total of 10,000 transactions/hr
- All the even number scripts need to generate a total of  5,000 transactions/hr
- The number of transactions generated by scripts 1 & 3 should represent 30% of the total traffic.
- the ramp up time for the script is 30 minutes and you want to run for 3 hrs once the ramp up is reached. You also want to use all 1000 vus.

For this scenario, determine the following –

- # vus assigned to each script
- average transaction time for each script (think-time settings)
- # of iterations for each script

Comment: And which is the question and the problem you are experiencing? Where is the work you have done on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reads like an interview or a classroom exercise question.    Let's turn this around:  What are your thoughts on how you would do this?    The answers are really independent of tool and involve basic math.

You should also clarify what the term "transaction" means here.  Depending upon who wrote the question for you to answer your math will change significantly.  Some common definitions of transaction are

- A Single Request:Response pair: A "Hit"
- A logical grouping of requests and responses which form a single unit, such as the loading of a single page which may contain dozens of requests and responses to fulfill the complete page response
- A complete business transaction, consisting of dozens of logical request groupings (i.e. taking ten pages to complete a business process)
- The result of a business process located in a data store independent of the web front end
- ...

Also, be sure to ask your mentor and trainer for insight

Comment: Thanks James Pulley.I am new to do load calculating.I got the question from one of friends.When i was trying to solve it,i found a question in my mind how many load generator is there? Do we need to know no of load generator? If we assume each transaction contains only 1 requests,how it's solution look like.Could you please help me out to solve it? If you give some idea i will appreciate that too Or some references please.

Comment: So then if each transaction is one request then a complex web page might have 75 to 100 transactions associated with the page for all of the page components that have to be requested and fulfilled?   So then once you know the requests per page then you will know the transactions per page and then you will know the transactions per business process and how long it takes to generate N transactions with natural pacing.    By The way, you as a tester should NEVER DEFINE what is 'Transaction' in some other author's requirement docment